# Lost reputation points after changing mail id

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

I created an account having username adn_295 and I had reputation 106. After that I opened an account which was also created by me (rep : 1 point, username : programmer_1) before but having different mail id.

Then I clicked on something like "Want to see comments sent you via e-mail" shown under the question I asked.

I entered mail id of second account by mistake and strangely the second account got the rep of 95 (which was "1" previously) and now the first primary account (username : adn_295) is gone. I am not able to login in it by entering correct username and pwd and it always redirects me to the second account i.e programmer_1.

So my questions are:

1. Is this behavior expected ?
2. What about my 11 rep points (106 - 95) that I lost ?
3. What about my primary account i.e uname : adn_295 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you verify an email via the link we sent you, you've confirmed you control that email address.  That email was also used on an OpenID login (yahoo) that verifies email.  Since you confirmed control of your email identity in both cases, we merged your accounts.

The lost rep was due to deleted questions since your last recalc - this is normal and wasn't really due to the merge process, any recalc would have had the same result.

As for your username, it picked the one from the older account...you can change that now if you wish.

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is expected. People should not have more than one account, so when the system identifies multiple accounts from same person it will perform automatic merge.

I don't know the exact triggers and details but know for sure such mechanism is in place.

When merge occurs, all the activity of the two accounts is merged, not much to explain here.
The account that was merged into other account is gone for good. Moderator might try to perform "manual split" but only in extreme cases where there shouldn't have been merge in the first place - in your case the merge was perfectly in place.

As for your lost 15 reputation it's most likely due to this question:

[Getting runtime error in IE8 using ext-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728887/getting-runtime-error-in-ie8-using-ext-js/8738990#8738990)

You probably asked it with one account and answered with your other account (which by the way is very rude) so the 15 rep gained from this trick were rightfully lost.

Comment: Nope...
I answered my own question as I found the solution later on. It was just to let others know the answer if they have similar question.

Comment: Maybe you done that in one of your other self accepted questions? Even by mistake? (Didn't notice you were using the other account)

Comment: You are free to answer your own question, but only with your own account. I.e. the one you wrote the question from. @pro

Comment: @slhck he claims that's what he did, only moderator can confirm that though.